# Webflux: Combining Flux<T> into a type with Collection<T>

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a type: A, which contains a collection i.e a List of b:

```
data class A(val b: List<B>,
             val value_in_b: String)

data class B(value_in_b: String)
```

I'm receiving a `Flux<A>` and `Flux<B>` from two sources where I can map a string to which will be in many instances of B. How do I combine these in Spring WebFlux?

answers in Kotlin or java are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer, for anyone who ends up here:

```
return clientForA.get()     //Flux<A>
            .map { a ->
                b.get(a.value_in_b)     //Flux<B>
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()) //Mono<MutableSet<B>>
                    .map { putColletionInA(a, b) }
            }
            .flatMap { it }
```